# ec2 scp -i mykey.pem Warning: Identity file mykey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory. Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, pem

Trying to upload simple a directory or file to an Amazon ec2 instance. I am using the command as follows in the standalone java ssh client and winscp:

```
scp -i mykey.pem ~/Downloads/zuni.jpg bitnami@ec2-184-72-159-94.compute-1.amazonaws.com:/home/bitnami/apps/magento/

Warning: Identity file mykey.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

Permission denied (publickey).

I tried finding the key on the instance and couldn't, even when I saw a bunch of other .pem keys. It's not finding the .pem file. Many people have this problem of uploading to ec2.

1. How do I find mykey.pem on the instance (I tried exhaustively and found /etc/ssl/certs but my key wasn't in there).
2. Why isn't this working?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

The key should be on your local machine not the instance. if you don't have one try generating it using aws admin page